# Python: Call functions out of a script

Tags: python, function, call

So let's say I have the following example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def hello():
    return "Hello, I am a script!"
def bye():
    return "Hope to see you again!"
```

If I call this script from the command line `python example.py`how can I access either `hello()` and/or `bye()`.

I just know how to call a function like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

Answer to comments:

- So there is no way of choosing which function to use out of the command line?
- I simply want a script containing like two differing table comparison functions and be able to choose out of one script which to use

Comment: You cannot access them after running the script, what are you actually wanting to do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html is your friend

Comment: you can use args to conditionally call the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to do this would be:

```
import sys

def hello():
    print "Hello world"

def goodbye():
    print "Goodbye, cruel world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func_name = sys.argv[1]
    func = globals()[func_name]
    func()
```

Then you can run `myscript.py hello` or `myscript.py goodbye`, and when you add other global/top level functions they will work immediately.

A better way to do this though would be to use something like `argparse` and maybe even https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Answer (score 5):

You can either:

```
python -c 'import example;example.hello()'
python -c '__import__("example").hello()'
```

Whatever the reason you ask this (other writers will tell you it is usually a better idea to use [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) or [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html), ... like they are doing in the stdlib [[timeit](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/timeit.py#L244) or [json](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/json/tool.py#L16)]), it **is** possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly call a function in a script with arguments to the script, you have to handle the command line arguments yourself and then call the function:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def hello():
    return "Hello, I am a script!"

def bye():
    return "Hope to see you again!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if arg == "hello":
            print hello()
        elif arg == "bye":
            print bye()
```

Of course you might want to extend this in several ways: to only process the first argument (this example processes all of them), to lowercase the argument so that `HELLO` and `BYE` also work, or maybe to display some help if no arguments are given.

As @bufh mentioned, if your command line arguments are going to get much more complicated than this then you might want to look into a library that handles it for you, such as [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html).